# to_xml giving strange results

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xml

When I do that

```
{"New York"=>33, :Versailles => 3231}.to_xml
```

I get

```
<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>
<hash>
  <Versailles type=\"integer\">3231</Versailles>
  <New York type=\"integer\">33</New York>
</hash>
```

I would have expected rails to dasherize "New York", no?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue is closed via the merging of pull request 445 : https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/445

Spaces will now be dasherized (and the private _dasherize method is enhanced to handle spaces.)

{"New York"=>33}.to_xml will result in

> `..<New-York type=\"integer\">33</New-York>..`

Thanks for putting up this lighthouse ticket & the stackoverflow question (which added more info in the discussions); with the help of all the information provided, I was able to make  my first rails commit!

Answer (score 0):

I'm seeing the same thing too.

According to the docs the `:dasherize` option to `to_xml` should do the trick.

> Some configuration is available through options. [...]
>   This behavior can be controlled with :only, :except, :skip_instruct, :skip_types, :dasherize and :camelize [...]
>   The default is to dasherize all column names, but you can disable this setting :dasherize to false. Setting :camelize to true will camelize all column names - this also overrides :dasherize.

So, it looks like, at a minimum:

```
asdf.to_xml(:dasherize => true)
```

should do it, and adding the `:camelize` option should force it.

```
=> "<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>\n<Hash>\n  <New York type="integer">33</New York>\n  <Versailles type="integer">3231</Versailles>\n</Hash>\n"
```

So, maybe someone can 'splain the anomoly.

Comment: The thing is that dasherize is changing underscore to dash, not space to dash. Same thing for camelize: "New_York is great".camelize = "NewYork is great". Nevertheless to_xml should not let us down with a malformed xml

Comment: About dasherize and space, Good point! Duh!, and, yes, to_xml should render valid XML or raise an exception or at least have a way to notify us of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Normally database fields don't have spaces in them, so your example in the context of #to_xml is a garbage-in-garbage-out situation.